# Omit object items

Tags: javascript

So this works:

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };

// Underscore/Lodash
var result = _.omit(object, ['a', 'c']);
console.log(result)
// output: { 'b': '2' }

// Native
var { a, c, ...result2 } = object;
console.log(result2)
// output: { 'b': '2' }
```

... but it doesn't work if my key has dashes:

```js
var object = { 'my-key': 1, 'b': '2', 'my-secret': 3 };
    
    // Underscore/Lodash
    var result = _.omit(object, ['a', 'c']);
    console.log(result)
    // output: { 'b': '2' }
    
    // Native
    var { 'my-key', 'my-secret', ...result2 } = object;
    console.log(result2)
    // Error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id",
    // expected output: { 'b': '2' }
```

Comment: From some quick testing, it doesn't have anything to do with the dashes, but rather with using quoted property keys (same thing happens if you replace `a` with `'a'` for example).

Comment: @JohnMontgomery without the quotes the dash is a syntax error.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I never said it wasn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use destructing like this you are assigning values to names even if you aren't using them. `my-key` isn't a valid variable name, so can't restructure into that name. You can, however, rename the keys in the destructuring and avoid the problem:

```js
var object = { 'my-key': 1,'b': '2','my-secret': 3};

var {'my-key': k, 'my-secret': k2, ...result2} = object;

console.log(result2)
```